# App is getting stucked for releasing memory in android:

Tags: android, memory

I am loading more than 500 images in a listview using Baseadapter  from the web service API but the view is getting stucked after setting the adapter . The progress dialog is dismissing after the async task operation, but it takes more than 4 seconds to load the images after the progress dialog is dismissed. I am  getting the following message in logcat:
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2740K, 31% free 30477K/44012K, paused 24ms, total 24ms

Comment: you need to use  in lazy-loading in Adapter or use Glide,Picasso for loading images

Comment: Thank you for  reply, I am already using the Picasso library for image downloading

Comment: show your adapter's `getView()` code?

Comment: I recommend showing your adapter's code you we are able to help you

Comment: show. us. your. code. please.

Answer (score 0):

Use universal image loader implemented by yourself or provided by volley apis.